# HTML5 issue with context.createPattern

Tags: html, canvas

I have a problem with the method `createPattern()`. I have this image as background pattern:

[image]

When I use it as a pattern, this is what I obtain:

[image]

Why, because I expect the output to be as follows:

[image]

I think that the problem can be caused in some previous setting of the context, but what type of setting can do this? However this is the specific code that I use to make the pattern:

```
var pattern_bg = new Image();
pattern_bg.src = 'bg.png';
pattern_bg.onload = function(){
   var pattern = context.createPattern(pattern_bg, "repeat");
   context.fillStyle = pattern;
   context.fillRect(0, 0, 223, 60);
}
```

Can please anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: The circle is repeating, as you've instructed. What do you expect the result to be (or rather, what are you trying to achieve)?

Comment: I wanted to include also the third image with the expected result, but I'm limited to only 2 link. If you can edit my post with the third image it would be great. This is the expected result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gwA2o.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the pattern that you want, you need to translate first at the point you want to be the origin of the fill, then draw from here.
So be sure to save() and restore() the context each time you change its transform matrix (translate, rotate, scale) to be able to set the translation as you want.

Do not forget you can always use setTransform to reset the matrix with `ctx.setTransform(1,0,1,0,0,0);`

I've done a very small jsbin to illustrate, here : 
http://jsbin.com/EYArASA/1/edit?js,output

We can see the result on this picture, fill is done directly on the left, and after a translate on the right.
[image: fill done directly on the left, after a translate on the right.]

Code is very simple, interesting part is this :

```
// rect drawn directly : wrong result
ctx.fillRect(10,20,64,64);

// canvas translated, then fillRect at 0,0 :
// right result
ctx.translate(116,20);
ctx.fillRect(0,0,64,64);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved using another canvas with another context to draw the pattern, and than copy it in the old canvas in the right position but I don't love my solution... now I try with your solution! Thank you!